# Batch script: The syntax of the command is incorrect - when script is going trough subdirectories?

Tags: syntax, batch-file, scripting, cmd, command-prompt

**Hello folks,**

my problem is probably very simple.

When I`m trying to use /r as a reference for batch script to go trough all the folders and subs in order to execute this small script I get the "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error.

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /r %%f in ("*[]*.*") do (
    set oldname=%%f
    set newname=!oldname:[]=!
    echo !oldname!
    echo !newname!
    pause
    ren !oldname! !newname!
)
```

However, when I remove /r this actually works, without any problem:

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for %%f in ("*[]*.*") do (
    set oldname=%%f
    set newname=!oldname:[]=!
    echo !oldname!
    echo !newname!
    pause
    ren !oldname! !newname!
)
```

So, how I can make the this script go trough all of the folders and subs, without problems as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include path information in the new file name when using REN. You can only include path information when specifying the original file name (and location). Any attempt to use REN with path info in 2nd argument gives the syntax error.

You can use `%%~nxf` to get just the name and extension of the file. Then do search and replace on that value to come up with the new name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%F in ("*[]*.*") do (
  set "newname=%%~nxF"
  set "newname=!newname:[]=!"
  echo %%F
  echo !newname!
  pause
  ren "%%F" "!newname!"
)
```

The above will fail if you ever run into a `!` in your original file name (or path). That can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%F in ("*[]*.*") do (
  set "oldname=%%F"
  set "newname=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "newname=!newname:[]=!"
  echo !oldname!
  echo !newname!
  pause
  ren "!oldname!" "!newname!"
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the fact that when you use /r you are getting the full path and when you do not use the /r you are only getting the file name.  Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /r %%f in ("*[]*.*") do (
    set oldname=%%f
    set newname=!oldname:[]=!
    call :NewFileNameOnly "!newname!"
    echo !oldname!
    echo !newname!
    pause
    ren "!oldname!" "!newname!"
)
goto :eof

:NewFileNameOnly
set newname=%~nx1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Use dbenham's solution.  It is simpler... no subroutine.